# 401 with node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have an url that when simply used on a browser gets results, but when used via `request` throws 401.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://server/platform/views/test.aspx?type=broadband&userdata=parameters', function (error, response, body){
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    console.log(body);          
else 
    console.log(response.statusCode);
})
```

I replaced my url with google.com and I do get results, so is there anything I need to tell `request` or something to be handled on the server I want to get data from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

401 in HTTP means that you are trying to access a ressource without any autorisation (you are not authenticated).

If the browser can access it, it's maybe because it has a stored cookie for that. Or maybe the server is parsing the User-Agent of the browser.

When you do a request with `request` like this, you have no cookie and minimal headers in your request (no User-Agent, no Referrer, ...).

Comment: yes, this is almost the question repeated in answer-form

Answer (score 0):

I report documentation link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication

also there is a tricky part here, sendImmediately should be set to false, because some server still send 401 reply if authentication headers are sent immediately